# How do I change the value in a column given a Boolean (in Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In a data frame, when the value of a given column is below 10, I need to change all the values till the end of the column to 5.

so let's say these are the values of the column:

| A |
| --- |
| 134 |
| 413 |
| 12 |
| 81 |
| 9 |
| 483 |
| 93 |
| 30 |

I would need it to become:

| A |
| --- |
| 134 |
| 413 |
| 12 |
| 81 |
| 5 |
| 5 |
| 5 |
| 5 |

I apologize if I didn't explain this well, I'm new to coding. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried the function `df.loc`? It helps you to filter those row with values less than 10 so that you can change it. Or a list comprehension will do. You can update your code if you have tried any

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the column value with `10` and get the `cummax` of boolean series to ensure the value after first True is True

```py
df['out'] = df['col'].mask(df['col'].lt(10).cummax().eq(1), 5)
```

```
print(df)

   col  out
0  134  134
1  413  413
2   12   12
3   81   81
4    9    5
5  483    5
6   93    5
7   30    5
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [134, 413, 12, 81, 9, 483, 93, 30, 6]})`.

- Find the elements that are less than 10: `df['x'] < 10`
- Find the row that contains the first of them: `(df['x'] < 10).argmax()`
- Change that row and all the following rows to 5

  ```
  df.loc[(df['x'] < 10).argmax():, 'x'] = 5
  ```

Answer (score -1):

you coutd try:
`myDataFrame = np.where(myDataFrame < 10, 5, myDataFrame)`

this checks where the value is lower than ten. if it is it sets it to five, else it just sets the value to what it already was.

Comment: The OP asks for a solution to a different problem.

Answer (score -2):

Let's assume the dataframe id `df` and the column name is `x`

```py
col_list = df['x'].to_list()
for i in range(len(col_list)):
    if col_list[i] < 10:
        col_list[i] = 5
df['x'] = col_list
```

Comment: This is a very un-pandas solution. In general, any "pandas" solution that involves a loop is not idiomatic.